# Mocha async test run twice when an adjacent test is present

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

This one is frustratingly puzzling.

I have the following test fixture:

```
describe('#post', function(){
    var options,
        bodyContent,
        bodyWriter;

    beforeEach(function(){
        // setup common objects ...
    });

    it('should have request body', function(done){
        httpHelper.post(options, bodyWriter, function(err, data){
            should.not.exist(err);
            should.exist(requestData.body);
            requestData.body.should.eql(bodyContent);
            done();
        });
    });

    // ...
});
```

Now, this works just fine - right up until the point where I add another test:

```
it('should contain path from options arg', function(done){
    httpHelper(options, bodyWriter, function(err, data){
        should.not.exist(err);
        requestData.options.path.should.eql(options.path);
        done();
    });
});
```

Now when I run the fixture, I get the following:

```
http
    #post
      ✓ should require options
      ✓ should have body
      1) should have body
      ✓ should contain path from options arg
```

I have no idea why this test is being run twice. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the `done` that is provided in the `should have body` (or `should have request body`???) test is called twice, the test would appear to run twice. If the callback that you pass to `httpHelper` is *registered* somewhere and this registration persists between tests, then when your second test executes, the callbacks in the first and second test would be executed.

Comment: That clue totally helped me identify the problem. Will post the code that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Louis's comment, I was able to identify the problem. One of the things I was doing in the test module was faking the native https module and injecting it using https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module. The problem was in my fake.

```
var fakeHttpsModule = (function(){
    var response = new EventEmitter(); 
    response.setEncoding = function(val){ /* no op */ };

    var request = function(options, callback) { 
        requestData.options = options;

        callback(response);
        return {
            write: function(value){
                requestData.body += value;
                response.emit('data', value);
            },
            end: function(){
                response.emit('end');
            },
            on: function(event, callback){ /* no op */ }
        };
    };

    return {
        request: request
    };
})();
```

The problem was based on the scope of the `response` object. By scoping it to the module, every time a test called the `request` method, that test's callback would ended up getting added as a registration to the `EventEmitter`. Hence, every test after the first one that called this method would get the error that `Done()` was called more than once.

The solution was to simply move the declaration of `response` so that it was scoped to the `request` function as follows.

```
var fakeHttpsModule = (function(){      
    var request = function(options, callback) { 
        requestData.options = options;

        var response = new EventEmitter(); 
        response.setEncoding = function(val){ /* no op */ };

        callback(response);
        return {
            write: function(value){
                requestData.body += value;
                response.emit('data', value);
            },
            end: function(){
                response.emit('end');
            },
            on: function(event, callback){ /* no op */ }
        };
    };

    return {
        request: request
    };
})();
```